# How do I access my "Current Screen" variable from within other classes?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a bunch of screens that all inherit from a base abstract class called GameScreen. They include various buttons that, if pressed, I want to use to change the Current Screen. For now, I am trying to change the screen from startScreen to overviewScreen.

I have a variable in my Game1 class:

```
public GameScreen CurrentScreen;
```

Which is initially set as:

```
CurrentScreen = startScreen;
```

I then use the following lines to Update and Draw the game, based on which screen is the Current screen:

```
CurrentScreen.Update();
...
CurrentScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

In my startScreen classs, I want to write something like this within the update method:

```
if (//Button is pressed)
{
     game.CurrentScreen = overviewScreen; 
}
```

Now clearly that won't work. But I can't see how to do it. Basically I want to access the CurrentScreen variable from within a class, and change it to whichever screen I want, and I feel like there must be a clean way to do this.

Let me know if any additional info is required, I feel like I haven't explained this at all well.

EDIT

startScreen and overviewScreen are classes that, primarily contain the Update and Draw methods for screens I want to display. GameScreen is a base class they all derive from. CurrentScreen is just meant to be a variable that determines which screen is active.

Comment: Please explain where do `startScreen` and `overviewScreen` objects come from. Also - what you wrote doesn't make any sense - your `GameScreen` derived classes include methods, that change mystical `CurrentScreen`, but in your code `CurrentScreen` is of type `GameScreen`. So you basically have a class, that changes itself? I'm not getting it.

Comment: Answers above so they can all be seen. Not sure I quite understand your questions (not because there's anything wrong with them, its me not understanding this properly!) but have done my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, notw it's cleaner for me. You could add few methods to your `Game1` class

```
public void SwitchToStartScreen(){...}
public void SwitchToOverviewScreen(){...}
//etc
```

Then you could add a property to your `startScreen` class (and other ones too)

```
public Game1 Parent {get;set;}
```

And force the constructor to pass `Game1` object, in which you would assign that parameter to `Parent` property. Then on particular condition you could just use

```
Parent.SwitchToOverviewScreen();
```

Accessing and changing properties manually from outer classes is violating object-oriented principles.

Also, use brief naming convention, because it's hard to understand what you wrote if one of class definitions uses Pascal case while other use Camel case. Your `startScreen` has more like an object name, while it's used like a class name. Eithar that or you're not seeing the difference between class and an object.
By default in C# Pascal case is used for declaring classes.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this, I'll give it a go. Apologies for the poor naming convention - I think (and hope!!) I know the difference between classes and objects, I'm entirely self taught and doing it as a hobby so probably not doing it in the right way!

Comment: Let me know if you'll encounter any problems. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

use the static objects

```
public static GameScreen CurrentScreen;
```

and same for the overviewScreen